Button work only on variables .NET 8 Blazor Web Assembly
I tried to modify my Counter.razor file with a Console.WriteLine, but nothing is printed inside of the console, and the counter get the +1.
I have my @rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly and can't set it to @rendermode InteractiveServer because I will need it for the future.
private void IncrementCounter()
{
    Console.WriteLine("ouiii");
    counter++;
} 


In Blazor WebAssembly, Console.WriteLine logs to the browser's developer console, not the server console. Here’s how you can log messages effectively:
Using JavaScript Interop

Add a JavaScript function in your _Host.cshtml or index.html:
<script>
    window.logToConsole = (message) => {
        console.log(message);
    };
</script>



like so

Call this function from your Blazor component:
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<button @onclick="IncrementCounter">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int counter = 0;

    private async void IncrementCounter()
    {
        counter++;
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("logToConsole", $"Counter: {counter}");
    }
}



Alternatively... you can:

Press F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I to open developer tools.
or,
Go to the "Console" tab to view the messages.

This way, you can log and view messages directly in the browser's console.

Only worked on Blazor Server before, didn't know that, thanks you !
